# How do you find the barycenter of a simplex covered by different coordinate neighbourhoods.

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

My issue is that I have a surface $S$ which is covered by a family of parametrizations {$x_a$} with a triangulation $\mathfrak{T}$ . I want to transform this triangulation into a triangulation that fits the following Proposition:

> Let $S$ be an oriented surface and $\{\mathbf{x}_a\}, a \in A$ a family of parametrizations compatible with the orientation of $S$. Let $R \subset S$ be a regular region of $S$. Then there is a triangulation $\mathfrak{T}$ of $R$ such that every triangle $T \in \mathfrak {T}$ is contained in some coordinate neighbourhood of the family $x_a$. Furthermore, if the boundary of every triangle of $\mathfrak{T}$ is positively oriented, adjacent triangles determine opposite directions in the common edge.

The most elegant way to do this seemed to me to be barycentric triangulation of the individual triangles. But I don't know how to find the barycenter of a triangle when its vertices are in different coordinate neighbourhoods.